# Rook and knight used together within the same move - legal?

Tags: engines, analysis, knights, rooks, illegal-move

This is my first question on chess beta and I don't know if I'm insane or if the cpu is broken. So I was playing chess against a CPU on the iPhone with the app 3D Chess Game, and the CPU (playing black) made an odd move.

Black to move:

[image: Black to move]

White to move (one move later):

[image: White to move]

I obviously edited this to simplify it, but the basic idea is same. That is:

**Black moves `Rook on a8 to d8` and `Knight on g8 to f6` in the same move.**

Is this legal? Or is it just a bug in the system?

Comment: It's busted unless you accidentally moved a piece or are playing in with a set of alternate rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's either a bug or some non standard chess variant